# Python reverse dictionary items order

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, reverse

Assume I have a dictionary:

```
d = {3: 'three', 2: 'two', 1: 'one'}
```

I want to rearrange the order of this dictionary so that the dictionary is:

```
d = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
```

I was thinking something like the `reverse()` function for lists, but that did not work. Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since Python 3.8 and above, the items view is iterable in reverse, so you can just do:

```
d = dict(reversed(d.items()))
```

On 3.7 and 3.6, they hadn't gotten around to implementing [`__reversed__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__) on `dict` and `dict` views ([issue33462: reversible dict](https://bugs.python.org/issue33462)), so use an intermediate `list` or `tuple`, which do support reversed iteration:

```
d = {3: 'three', 2: 'two', 1: 'one'}
d = dict(reversed(list(d.items())))
```

Pre-3.6, [you'd need `collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (both for the input and the output) to achieve the desired result. Plain `dict`s did not preserve any order until CPython 3.6 (as an implementation detail) and Python 3.7 (as a language guarantee).

Answer (score 2):

Standard Python dictionaries (Before Python 3.6) don't have an order and don't guarantee order.  This is exactly what the creation of `OrderedDict` is for.

If your Dictionary was an `OrderedDict` you could reverse it via:

```
import collections

mydict = collections.OrderedDict()
mydict['1'] = 'one'
mydict['2'] = 'two'
mydict['3'] = 'three'

collections.OrderedDict(reversed(list(mydict.items())))
```

Comment: Actually, as of 3.6 (CPython/PyPy implementation detail) and 3.7 (as language guarantee) plain `dict` is insertion ordered, just like `OrderedDict`. `OrderedDict` provides a few additional APIs for manipulating the order, but you don't need it for simple reversals.

Comment: what makes you think this is wrong?  Here's a demo showing that it works: https://repl.it/repls/ExtraneousAllFormula

Comment: @Bradd: The wrong part was back when this answer claimed `dict`s were always unordered (when they've been ordered on modern CPython for over two years now).

Answer (score 1):

Another straightforward solution, which is guaranteed to work for Python v3.7 and over:

```
d = {'A':'a', 'B':'b', 'C':'c', 'D':'d'}
dr = {k: d[k] for k in reversed(d)}

print(dr)
```

Output:

```
{'D': 'd', 'C': 'c', 'B': 'b', 'A': 'a'}
```

Note that reversed dictionaries are still considered equal to their unreversed originals, i.e.:

```
(d == dr) == True
```

In response to someone upvoting this comment, I was curious to see which solution is actually faster.

As usual, it depends. Reversing a 10,000 item dictionary 10,000 times is faster with the solution using `list` and `reversed` on the items. But reversing a 1,000,000 item dictionary 100 times (i.e. the same number of items in total reversed dictionaries, just a bigger starting dictionary) is faster with the comprehension - it's left up to the reader to find the exact point where it flips. If you deal with large dictionaries, you may want to benchmark either if performance matters:

```
from random import randint
from timeit import timeit


def f1(d):
    return dict(reversed(list(d.items())))


def f2(d):
    return {k: d[k] for k in reversed(d)}


def compare(n):
    d = {i: randint(1, 100) for i in range(n)}
    print(timeit(lambda: f1(d), number=100000000 // n))
    print(timeit(lambda: f2(d), number=100000000 // n))


compare(10000)
compare(1000000)
```

Results (one run, typical results):

```
4.1554735
4.7047593
8.750093200000002
6.7306311
```