# Python: Reverse order of dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to reverse the order of a string i.e. If i have:

```
dictionaryA = {'A':'a', 'B':'b', 'C':'c', 'D':'d'}
```

i want to rearrange it to where it's:

```
{'D':'d','C':'c', 'B':'b', 'A':'a'}
```

Why won't splicing work? ([::-1])? And reverse() too? How can you rearrange the order of each dictionary entry?

Comment: Although dictionaries in current versions of Python do preserve order, why do you need to change the order? In what use case is that important?

Comment: just `dict(reversed(dictionaryA.items())` on the most recent versions of Python, you may have to do `dict(reversed(list(dictionaryA.items()))`

Comment: What did you try? This should work : `reversed = dict(list(dictionaryA.items())[::-1])`

Comment: To add to @paisanco answer, you can also check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/12749132.

Comment: Please note that this only works for python > 3.6 as the order of the dictionary is maintained when it items are added.

Comment: @cvanelteren to be pedantic, that was an implementation detail in Python 3.6, but guaranteed in Python 3.7 +

Comment: @cvanelteren really should avoid use builtin names (`reversed`) as variables.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: To be precise, `reversed` became supported for `dict` and `dict` views as of 3.8. The `list` conversion would be needed on 3.6/3.7.

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn No worries was just a quick inline example. Oddly enough `argparse` also uses builtin-names as variable names and annoys me a lot too.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, as the linked question and answer is specific to python 2.7 - this question is about Python in general (and assumed to be Python 3)

Comment: @Grismar [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55911745/python-reverse-dictionary-items-order) is specifically about Python 3.

Comment: @Grismar: The one other people voted for initially was 2.7; the one I dupe hammered to is 3.x (and recent enough to cover the different behaviors from 3.5 and earlier, 3.6-3.7 and 3.8+). Between the two of them the question is definitely answered.

Comment: `d[::-1]` would not be pretty because it would imply other kinds of slicing may also work, but dicts can not be efficiently accessed by index and general slices (start, stop, step) seems ambiguous - what should `d[:1]` return?  As for a `d.reverse()` method, it's probably just not something that is needed very often so nobody bothered to implement...

Comment: @ShadowRanger fair enough - it's one that keeps coming up, but I'm happy to post the below there as an alternative approach as well. I cannot retract my vote to reopen, it seems? (happy to leave it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very straightforward solution (although it's unclear why you'd need it):

```
d = {'A':'a', 'B':'b', 'C':'c', 'D':'d'}
dr = {k: d[k] for k in reversed(d)}

print(dr)
```

Output:

```
{'D': 'd', 'C': 'c', 'B': 'b', 'A': 'a'}
```

Comment: Note that `d == dr` is still `True`, so dictionaries being "ordered" in Python 3.6+ is a limited concept. `OrderedDict(d) == OrderedDict(dr)` would be `False`.