# Initialize non existing keys in OrderedDict with default values like defaultDict

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to access the non existing keys in OrderedDict with default values like which we do in defaultDict

```
Ex.
od = OrderedDict({'a':1})
print(od['b'])  # Output: KeyError: 'b'
```

This is the real problem `KeyError` is thrown in the following implementation

```
l =['a','b','c','b']
od = OrderedDict({})

for k in l:
    od[k] += 1 # KeyError
```

This implementation is intentionally avoided

```
for k in l:
    if k in od:
        od[k] += 1
    else:
        od[k] = 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement an ordered, default dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190331/how-to-implement-an-ordered-default-dict)

Comment: @Arne, the link provided is about implementation of a new custom Dict Type. I am trying to use features from library directly if there any features available in `OrderedDict` or if there any other Type available similar to `OrderedDict` in  other libraries

Comment: Is this for code that will have to run in Python <3.7 (or <3.6 in the default C implementation)? Because if not, [dictionaries now maintain insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/12975140) even without using OrderedDict.

Comment: @CrazyChucky, It will be implemented in Python >= 3.7. Scenario is to do `dd['b'] += 1`.  This will throw `KeyError` Exception if default `dd['b'] = 0` is not assigned before.

Comment: @JanPo Then just use defaultdict. It maintains its insertion order. You don't need OrderedDict.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The above comment is intended to use with `od` instead of `dd`
 Scenario is to do `od['b'] `+= 1. This will throw `KeyError` Exception if default `od['b']` = 0 is not assigned before.

Comment: I understand that. I'm just saying that if the reason you need OrderedDict is to maintain key order, you don't actually need it at all, because defaultdict now does that all in its own (and so does plain ol' dict). Or is there another reason you need to use OrderedDict specifically?

Comment: In other words, if you explain why you need OrderedDict instead of defaultdict, we might be better able to help you.

Comment: Considering about compatibility with previous python versions. It would be nice if i could have additional information why do we need another additional `OrderedDict` data structure in `collection` if `deafaultDict` could do all sorting/ordering now.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include why current Python has both.

Answer (score 2):

Just inherit from `OrderedDict` and redefine `__getitem__`:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict


class OrderedDictFailFree(OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        try:
            return OrderedDict.__getitem__(self, name)
        except KeyError:
            return None


od = OrderedDictFailFree({'a': 1})
print(od['b'])
```

Comment: What if you also redefined `__init__` to accept the default value (or callable, to replicate the way defaultdict works)?

Comment: If you're implementing this by hand, the correct way is to define `__missing__` instead of overriding `__getitem__`. You can completely delete the definition of `__getitem__` and define `def __missing__(self, key): return None` and it will behave exactly the same as the above, except *significantly* more efficiently for lookups where the key already exists.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly doable, as [Yevgeniy Kosmak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70526584/12975140) shows. However, keep in mind that in Python >=3.7 (or even >=3.6 as long as you're using the default CPython implementation), all dictionaries now [maintain insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared/39537308#39537308) anyway. So in the event that you don't need compatibility with older versions, and the only thing you need is keys that maintain order, you may very well not need `OrderedDict` at all. `defaultdict` will maintain its order just as well.

There are still [some differences](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) between `OrderedDict` and `dict`/`defaultdict`, however, which may or may not affect your use case. These include:

- Equality checks between two `OrderedDict`s check not only keys/values, but order as well. (This is not true of two `defaultdict`s, or an `OrderedDict` checked against a `defaultdict`.)
- An `OrderedDict`'s [`move_to_end()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.move_to_end) method can efficiently move a key/value pair to the front or end.
- An `OrderedDict`'s [`popitem()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem) method can optionally pop and return the *first* key/value instead of the last. (`dict`'s [`popitem()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) returns the last-inserted key/value—or, prior to 3.7, an arbitrary pair.)
- Prior to 3.8, `dict`/`defaultdict` didn't directly support reverse iteration, such as with `reversed()`. However, in 3.6 or 3.7 [you can still achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55911745/python-reverse-dictionary-items-order/55911834#55911834) with an intermediary list or tuple.

---

Note: Even if `dict` now replicated all of `OrderedDict`'s functionality, the latter would still probably not be removed from Python. Existing older programs already use OrderedDict, and Python usually tries not to break existing code with new minor version releases (e.g. 3.6 to 3.7) unless there's a compelling reason, like adding new keywords to the syntax. See [here](https://devguide.python.org/devcycle/) for more info on the Python versioning system, and [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0387/) for details on backwards compatibility specifically.

Comment: 3. Someone might want the advantages that `OrderedDict` still has.

Comment: Check out [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Note the two methods and their parameters, and the order-sensitive comparisons mentioned there. I think I've also used `OrderedDict` for its `popitem(False)` a while ago because it was much *faster* than doing the equivalent with a regular dict.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thank you! I can't believe I missed that somehow. I have edited my answer, and learned new things to boot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we could use `od.setdefault('b',0)` although it's not that elegant solution.

```
od = OrderedDict({'a':1})
print(od.setdefault('b',0)) # od.get('b',0) could be used if intention is not to change od
```

```
l =['a','b','c','b','b']
od = OrderedDict({})

for k in l:   
    od[k] = od.setdefault(k,0) + 1 # set key to 0 if there in no key k and increment by 1
```

Comment: You can just do `od[k] = od.setdefault(k, 0) + 1` (or `od[k] = od.get(k, 0) + 1` with equivalent effect in this case); `setdefault` returns the existing value (or the newly set default value when it was previously unset) so it can be inlined.

Comment: That's good suggestion. I will edit accordingly